# Cant send UDP broadcast on Mac OSX using Node.js

Tags: node.js, macos, udp, broadcast, datagram

im using this code (official node sample):

```
const dgram = require('dgram');
const message = Buffer.from('Some bytes');
const client = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
client.send(message, 12345, '192.168.1.255', (err) => {
  client.close();
});
```

to send a broadcast packet on network.
But I get a 'EACCES' error on mac (no problem on windows).
Note: I can send to a specific address (for example 192.168.1.11) successfully, the problem is with broadcasting ...

any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems i need a

```
.setBroadcast(true);
```

(after binding)
that fixed my problem.